# Horizontal CSS - Input Field 100% and Margin for button

Tags: html, css

**Task:** Make text box 100% width but allow enough room for button.

**Problem:** Button appears on next line and text box exceeds width of its container.

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="my-field" />
    <input type="button" id="my-button" value="Add +" />
</div>

 .field {
     margin-right: -70px;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .field input[type=text] {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 70px;
 }
 .field input[type=button] {
     display: block;
     float: right;
 }
```

My primary layout uses the following trick to achieve flexible width with fixed sidebar, but for some reason this is not working on the above.

```
<div class="outer-wrap">
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        ...
    </div>
 </div>

 .outer-wrap {
     margin-right: -300px;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .content {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 300px;
 }
 .sidebar {
     float: right;
 }
```

What mistake am I making here?

Comment: It's ok to use tables for layout when you need to pull tricks like this to accomplish the wanted result. Horizontal alignment is just a pain in the ass without tables and there's no reason to not use them.

Comment: @MikaTähtinen inability to create normal print versions is quite big reason not to use table for page layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to screw with the HTML a bit, but otherwise this works perfectly in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/25bZC/

**CSS:**

```
.field > span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px
}
.field input[type=text] {
    width: 100%
}
.field input[type=button] {
    float: right
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="button" id="my-button" value="Add +" />
    <span><input type="text" name="my-field" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the fix, and for the link to jsfiddle! Would you mind explaining why that works? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: You're welcome. I forget to include the usual explaining link, [here it is](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

Answer (score 2):

To pull this off you must ensure that the element which you are floating right comes before the one floating left. Like this

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="button" id="my-button" value="Add +" />
    <input type="text" name="my-field" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving fixed width to

```
field input[type=text]
```

and

```
.field input[type=button]
```