# flexible elements in div element

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
            <div class="search-box-wrapper">                
                <div class="search-box">
                    <span class="search-lbl">Search</span>
                    <span><input type="submit" name="search" value="Find" class="search-btn" /></span>
                    <span><input class="search-text" type="text" name="lookingfor" value=" " /></span>                        
                </div>                
        </div>
```

how can I make `{input type="text"}` element with flexible size? I mean `search-lbl` and `search-btn` will be around `type="text"` element, but `search-text` can change it's size.

Comment: @TheZ this group (label, textbox, button) must take 100% of parent div element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
input[type="text"]
{
width:100%;
}
```

However this might not be compatible with all browsers - I may have also missunderstoond @ckarlss0n may be right with text-area.

Comment: these elements must be on the same line. In your case input[type="text"] takes 100% width and displaces another elements

Comment: Wezly look at http://www.amazon.com/ search label, textbox and search button are on the same line and textbox can change it's width on resizing browser window

Comment: @Wachburn Inspect the source of amazon.com - looks like they might be using some javascript to resize the text box ensuring space for their button.

Comment: Wezly i found solution, but i don't understand how it works)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815458/horizontal-css-input-field-100-and-margin-for-button

Comment: This is the explanation he gives - [http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats)

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you able to give it a width and a height in CSS?

`.search-text{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}>`

Maybe I misunderstood you. For a flexible text input element, check out text-area!